# Passing variable with jQuery AJAX not working in Firefox and Safari, works in Chrome

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, firefox

html

```
<li><a class="download-link" href="<?php echo $path_data;?>">Download</a></li>
```

ajax

```
$(function(){
        $('.download-link').click(function() {
            var wall_id = <?php echo $wall_id;?>;   //store current wall id
            $.ajax({
                type    : 'GET',
                url     : 'functionality/php/download_count.php',
                data    : { wall_id : wall_id }
            });         //ajax end
        });             //live end
    });                 //function end
```

php (`download_count.php`)

```
<?php

    $wall_id = preg_replace("#[^0-9]#", "", $_GET['wall_id']);

    //increment download count query
    $increment_downloads = $connectDB->prepare("UPDATE database.table SET
                          downloads = downloads + 1 WHERE wall_id = ?");
        $increment_downloads->bind_param('i', $wall_id);
        $increment_downloads->execute();
    ?>
```

I'm trying to update `download count` when the `Download` link is clicked. But the downloads in by table don't increment. Not sure where the problem is. Need help.

**Update:** Above code NOT working in Firefox and Safari, but works fine with Chrome.

Comment: Do you see the correct `wall_id` when you view source?

Comment: @Barmar yes! I see the correct `wall_id`.

Comment: alert wall_id befire sending ajax call

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, what is that for? just to check? Then I guess no need since I can confirm the wall_id is correct.

Comment: whats your print_r($increment_downloads) says before the execute command ?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing quotes around the value of `var wall_id`

```
var wall_id = <?php echo $wall_id;?>;
```

should be

```
 var wall_id = "<?php echo $wall_id;?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

change your ajax

```
    $('.download-link').click(function(){
        var wall_id = <?php echo $wall_id;?>;   //store current wall id
        $.ajax({
            type    : 'GET',
            url     : 'functionality/php/download_count.php',
            data    : { wall_id : wall_id }
        });     //ajax end
    });
```

to

```
    $.get( "functionality/php/download_count.php", { wall_id : wall_id } )
        .done(function( data ) {
        alert( data );
    });
```

then add this to the end of you php script

```
    echo $_GET['wall_id'];
```

then let me know if you are getting the right value

Comment: also this line var wall_id = <?php echo $wall_id;?>; to var wall_id = '<?php echo $wall_id;?>';

Comment: my thought is that you are not really able to assign the php value to your javascript variable.

Comment: I'm able to I think. I've added `beforeSend:function({$('.body').html(wall_id);}` to my code, and it outputs the correct `wall_id`.

Comment: also you should practice using the console of most browser for you to map what causes the failure of your script.

browsers like Google C  and firefox have this tool. just press F12 and go to console tab and see what actually is wrong.

Comment: if you are able to put the variable correctly, edit your php script and just put this echo $_GET['wall_id'];

you should be able to see the alert with your correct ID Using the code i provided

if still you are not able to get the value. check your URL if it is correct.